# Почему "крем" - заварной?

Tags: семантика

Интересуют значения прилагательного в терминах разного рода кремов.

Сливочный, яичный, масляный, молочный... - всё было бы понятно, если в разные рецепты каждого из них не входили все эти компоненты.

***Но больше всего проблем с заварным кремом. Как можно популярно объяснить, что там заваривают?***

Особенно порадовала рецептура пирожного *эклер:* ***заварное тесто с заварным кремом.*** как это может быть?

*Проблема в том, что на французском, если верить википедии, нет такого понимания слова "крем", что он делится на сливочный там или заварной. Впрочем, я с французским вообще не очень дружу. Но на английском и даже немецком кремом называют вообще всё что угодно.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

бегемот, я, кажется, понял, чего вы не понимаете.

В заварном креме **заваривают** именно **муку**.

Разделять крем на яичный, сливочный и т. д. и "заварной" было бы бессмысленно, если бы не образующее, соединяющее вещество. Этот компонент может составлять даже незначительную долю общей массы изделия, но он определяет структуру и технологию производства. Если основа - масляная, то и крем масляный, если сливочная - то и крем сливочный. При этом все прочие компоненты могут входить в состав рецепта как наполнители в любых количествах, это не изменит классификацию крема.

В заварном креме такая основа - "заваренная" мука, то есть жиденькое тесто, схватившееся в результате добавления горячей воды. Это и есть процесс заварки. Вода, разумеется, совсем не обязана быть крутым кипятком (обычно это даже вредно), но оно должна быть достаточно горячей. Дальнейшие действия, даже если там что-то варят, уже не важны для классификации. Заварной крем - это крем на основе заваренной муки. Иное употребление неверно. Горячее молоко само по себе не делает крем заварным, что и отразилось в названии найденного вами рецепта.

Comment: Интересная мысль. Я готов поверить, если вы где-то найдете подтверждение того, что заваривают именно тесто. А кашу заварить - это как?

Comment: Ну про крем я просто знаю. Объясняли специалисты, пришлось мне в кондитерской промышленности поработать. Про кашу - не знаю.  думаю, что смысл тот же, только не мука заваривается, а зерно, цельное или дробленое.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о кондитерском креме, всё просто.Нужно посмотреть рецепт приготовления, там всё ясно:заварной, потому что его заваривают.

1.Засыпаем ваниль в кастрюлю с молоком. Туда же добавим половину всего сахара, который собираемся использовать.Теперь эту смесь аккуратно доводим до кипения. Как только молоко закипело, нужно снять его с огня и минут 20-30 дать ему как следует настояться. В это время весь аромат ванили впитается в нашу смесь.Теперь возьмем отдельную миску и высыпаем туда крахмал или же предварительно прошедшую этап просеивания муку. Туда же отправляем сахарный песок. Все перемешиваем при помощи венчика.Теперь в сухую часть нашего будущего соуса нужно добавить цельные яйца или яичные желтки. Затем все перемешайте так, чтобы смесь стала однородной.Тем временем наше ванильное молоко нужно снова прокипятить (стручки ванили можете убрать).Как только молоко закипит, влейте одну треть в часть, состоящую из яиц и крахмала.Далее все вновь тщательно перемешайте при помощи венчика.Помешивайте смесь и одновременно с этим влейте в нее остатки молока. Помешивать смесь можно венчиком или деревянной лопаткой. Ждите, когда крем загустеет.
Если в основе заварного крема использовался крахмал, дайте ему закипеть и после этого поварите еще пару минут. Если же крем делался на мучной основе, до кипения доводить не надо.

Или ещё - 2.Соединить 2 яйца, 1 стакан сахара и 3 ст.л. муки. Хорошо всё растереть в однородную массу.Затем постепенно вводим молоко, буквально по 1-2 столовой ложке и хорошо вымешиваем, чтобы не было комков. Должна получиться однородная масса.Ставим кастрюлю на средний огонь и доводим до кипения. Как только молочная масса закипит, сразу снимаем с огня и даём остыть до комнатной температуры.Разминаем сливочное масло (важно чтобы оно было хорошо размягчённым) и добавляем молочную массу по 1 столовой ложке.Затем очень интенсивно перемешиваем, чтобы не было комков, и молоко с маслом хорошо соединились.Постепенно вводим всё заваренное молоко и хорошо перемешиваем.
Готовый крем можно использовать как для торта «Наполеон», так и для других десертов.

Или ещё проще-3:

Желтки хорошо растереть с сахаром и какао, добавить распущенный в кипящем молоке шоколад и довести крем до кипения, после чего крем охладить.

А вот незаварные кремы готовят из холодных продуктов.Масляный - из масла и сгущёнки, яичный из взбитых яиц с сахаром и т.д. Они все разные, и о составе говорит название.

И тесто заварное заваривают:

В небольшую кастрюлю налить воду, положить масло, соль и довести до кипения. Всыпать муку, постоянно помешивая деревянной ложкой, варить 1~2 мин.

Comment: Рецепты я смотрел. Не видел там слова "заваривать" )))  Насколько я понимаю по вашим текстам, "заварным" нечто становится после доведения чего-то до кипения? А как же чай?

Comment: Из холодных, говорите? Вот первый попавшийся. Рецепт ***приготовления сливочного крема*** из красной смородины
    Перебираем смородину, очищаем от плодоножек, промываем, оставляем постоять, чтобы стекла лишняя жидкость.
    Перетираем ягоды в пюре.
    Заливаем желатин холодной водой, оставляем набухать.
  ***Подогреваем молоко с ванилью примерно до 80 градусов.***
    Взбиваем с сахаром желтки, вводим в теплое молоко вместе с желатином, ставим на минимальный огонь, прогреваем, постоянно помешивая, но не доводим до закипания....

Comment: @behemothus, **варить** можно только  в *кипящей* воде.

Comment: @user244413  *варить можно только в кипящей воде* - нет, не только, с чего вы взяли?!  Но это и не имеет отношения к вапросу. Мы говорим о слове "заваривать", а не варить. Довольно странно было бы считать крем (или что еще) заварным в том случае, если один их компонентов - вода кипящая, а не, скажем, при 95 градусах. Кстати, именно 95 градусов - оптимальная температура для заварки чая.

Comment: Скажите уж просто: "по историческим причинам".

Comment: У слова заваривать по Ефремовой 3 значения:
Заваривать - 1. Заливать кипятком для получения настоя. 
2. разг. Приготовлять путем варки или заливания кипятком. // перен. Затевать, начинать что-л., требующее активных действий. 
3. Устранять трещины, пустоты, отверстия и т.п. в металле путем сварки.  http://tolkslovar.ru/z313.html  У нас второе значение- приготовлять путём варки или доведения до кипения. А чай и травы заваривают в 1 значении, это настои. Заварное тесто именно варят 1-2 мин., тогда оно становится пустым внутри и туда можно шприцем поместить крем.

Comment: И в заварной крем проваривают смесь с крахмалом, чтобы густой кисель получился, и смесь с сахаром, чтоб он растаял, проваривают, а муку заваривают почти кипятком, чтобы тоже клейстер получился, а потом уже остужают и смешивают с маслом или ещё с чем.